# ffmpeg encoding with VP8 producing bad looking video

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am working at a time lapse program that invokes ffmpeg via system() to encode a video from a sequence of JPGs. The user can chose a few options, including the compression codec.
I am getting very good results when using libx264 and the mjpeg encoder. I am getting so and so results with VP9, and I am getting some horrible results with VP8.

I am invoking ffmpeg like so: ffmpeg.exe -framerate 12 -i "./output/img_%05d.jpg"  -dst_range 1 -color_range 2 -c:v libvpx -b:v 0 -threads 8 -speed 2 -crf 8 "./output/video.webm"

I uploaded a sample to youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eG2jxzR3Uxs (you can see the really bad frames after the 9 seconds mark.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: This is a very old issue, but for anyone looking at a similar problem, -b:v 0 sets the max bitrate for vp9 to no limit, but for vp8 it sets it to 256kbps. This will kill video quality no matter the crf preset. If you want no limit, you need to set it to something high, like 100M.

Answer (score 3):

Even with CRF (see also the libvpx [wiki](http://wiki.webmproject.org/ffmpeg/vp9-encoding-guide)), you are still recommended to use 2-pass encoding for best results. The 1-pass (which is what you're using here) typically gives pretty poor results with libvpx. I know that's not typical, CRF should not be affected by multi-pass, but unfortunately libvpx is a little bit "different" in that regard. Other encoders will work fine with 1-pass CRF.

Also note that even though CRF indices are the same, you're not necessarily selecting the same effective quantizer or getting anywhere near the same bitrate. So that fact that one encoder or code gives better results than another without taking effective bitrate into account isn't very useful in and by itself, you'd typically analyze quality as a function of bitrate.

This can be somewhat improved by using VBR, but even then, the actual bitrate may be quite far from the target bitrate if the rate control/targetting is poor, so you still need to look at actual bitrate, not just target bitrate.

Comment: I am using a different CRF for each compression (for example, libx264 likes it between 18 and 28 or something like that). Would it be better if I manually set a bitrate?

Comment: Also, I am using virtually the same settings for both vp8 and vp9, and the vp9 one gives me much better (but nowhere near x264) results. See the vp9 movie here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=achbQzpZ7YY

Comment: If one wanted to stick to a single-pass, what's the recommended command?

Comment: I understand that some people might want to use single-pass, and the command above will do what you're asking. However, the quality will not be great with libvpx. Youtube isn't great to compare quality because it recompresses itself. If you want to compare quality across encoders/codecs, you can use either CRF or VBR (bitrate), but the critical thing is to compare bitrate/quality points against each other, not a single output file with a similar VBR target or CRF setting, because the actual bitrate may be very different.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't use 2 passes, because I apply some slow filters first, so that would really take a very long time.

Comment: The videos on youtube look more or less as they look on my computer, the artifacts you see there are more or less what I see in VLC.

Comment: Ok, so I found the solution here: https://superuser.com/questions/1280255/ffmpeg-vp8-single-pass-conversion In short, unlike vp9, you shouldn't use -b:v 0 :)

Comment: @Radu That's not expected. As mentioned in my answer (I didn't see this post), I assume something screws up the rate control there. In any case, setting some reasonable bitrate constraint may help.